# Determine the cardinality of a set

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, proof-verification

I will give some simplified definitions of my problem.

> Consider $\{1,\dotsc,T\}$ with $T\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\theta<T$ and
>   $M$ positive integers. Say that the points $l$ and $l'$ are
>   **separated** if $\mid l-l'\mid>M$. Finally, define the set $\Gamma=\{(l,l',k,k'): l, l',l_\theta+(k-1)\theta \text{ and }
>  l_\theta' + (k'-1)\theta$ are not separated from each
>   other$\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}^4$, where $l_\theta=l-\left
>  \lfloor{\frac{l-1}{\theta} }\right \rfloor \theta$ (this function just
>   brings $l$ back to the point $l_\theta \in \{1,\dotsc,\theta\}$, or
>   equivalentely, $l$ can be seem as $l_\theta\in \{1,\dotsc,\theta\}$
>   plus a multiple of $\theta$).

I want to show that $\#\Gamma\leq CT^2M^2$ for some positive constant $C$.

**My attempt**

Define the $\Gamma_0=\{(l,k):l $ and $ l_\theta+(k-1)$ are not separated$ \}$. In the interval $[1,1+M]$, the points $\{1,1+\theta,\dotsc,1+\left \lfloor{\frac{M}{\theta} }\right \rfloor\theta \}$ are not separated from each other since $\mid 1 - (1+\left \lfloor{\frac{M}{\theta} }\right \rfloor\theta)\mid\leq M $. It immediately follows that 
$$S_1:=\{(1,1),\dotsc, (1,\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor),(1+\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor\theta,1),\dotsc,(1+\theta,1)\}\subseteq \Gamma_0,$$
and that $\# S_1=2\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor-1$.

*Note that as the points $1$ and $1+\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor\theta$ are not separated, then $(l=1,k=\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor)$ and $(l=1+\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor\theta,k=1)$ are both in $\Gamma_0$. If you prefer, associate these two doubles of indices to the doubles of points $(1,1+\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor\theta)$ and $(1+\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor\theta,1)$, respectively.

Also, observe that for any interval $[s,s+M]:s\in\{1,\dotsc,T-M\}$, we also have $\#S_s=2\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor-1$. If $s>T-M$, then $\#S_s\leq 2\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor-1$ such that the cardinality decreases monotonically to $1$ as the integer $s$ approaches to $T$ (when $s=T$, only $(T,1)\in\Gamma_0$). As $\{S_s\}_{s=1}^T$ is a partition of $\Gamma_0$ , then $\#\Gamma_0=\#\cup S_s\leq T(2\left \lfloor{M/\theta }\right \rfloor-1)\leq C  (TM)$, for some positive constant $C$.

By noting that $\Gamma\subseteq \{(a,b):a,b\in \Gamma_0\}$ and this latter has cardinality smaller than $C  (TM)^2$, we conclude that $\#\Gamma\leq C  (TM)^2$ for some $C>0$.

Do you accept my proof? I appreciate to receive feedbacks!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all the variables integers?  I.e. $l, l', k, k', \theta$ etc

Comment: @antkam Yes! they are all natural numbers

Comment: As defined, $\Gamma$ is infinite. Is it supposed to be a subset of $[T]^4$ instead of $\mathbb{N}^4$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor you are right. Can you explain me the meaning of this notation $[T ]$, just for a clean understanding?

Comment: It's shorthand notation for $\{1,\dotsc,T\}$